# Slow page load except with html extension

Tags: php, html, dom

I have two files that are exactly the same:

http://bertmeeus.be/newsite/html/so.html

http://bertmeeus.be/newsite/html/so.php

except the extension is different.

The load time of the two pages is very different.
The html file loads immediately where the php file take 5 seconds to load.

I've checked it in chrome console: html: 21ms, php: 5.16s

Is there anything I can do to improve the speed of loading?

This is a really simple file but when I code some jQuery. I cannot use the functionality before the page is loaded (5sec.)

Comment: The static page(.html) will almost always load faster. There can be a lot of processing happening in the `.php` file. So the only way to help you is to see what the .php file is doing

Comment: http://bertmeeus.be/newsite/html/so.html - 33ms waiting; 12ms receiving... http://bertmeeus.be/newsite/html/so.php - 71ms waiting; 0ms receiving in chrome console.... what actual PHP tags do you have in the .php file? How much memory is configured for php, how many php modules are you loading? etc

Comment: my php tags start with <??>  but i have the same issue with <?php ?> tags

Comment: i think @MarkBaker, question was more what is in the php file.  You said it is exactly the same as the html file. then  why the php tags?  assuming the only difference is <? ?> at the top. or are you actually running php code to dynamically generate the page? if they are the same, not dynamic content, why force the webserver to use php to process the page?

Comment: For this example i've made the same files just another extension. there is no php code inside the php file.

Comment: I've removed my answer because I can only offer theories right now. I noticed that "Hello World" does get printed before the loading spinner stops spinning so I wonder if you have some weird output buffering going on which might be causing your issue. I would check out the documentation http://php.net/manual/en/function.ob-start.php and see if you can come up with some tests involving turning it on/off.

Comment: @MonkeyZeus that's the whole point. The loading spinners keeps spinning for 5 sec. Meanwhile i cannot do anything. **Is it a server issue?** Even without php code in my file, the loading keeps going on. Not for the .html-file.

Comment: Any idea what PHP version you are using? Maybe your hosting company upgraded and it has bugs. What's the output from `phpinfo()`?

Comment: It's ver 5.2.8 you can check the output: http://bertmeeus.be/newsite/html/so.php

Comment: hmm, what would happen if you simply executed `die();` on your page with no other HTML or PHP? If it still takes 5 seconds then I think it is safe to say this is a server issue and most likely one that is out of your control. It looks like Hostmaster is using IIS6 as well and IIS7 is the newest. If it doesn't break your stuff then see if you can switch to an Apache server. Good Luck!

Comment: It's the same. My hosting tells me their is nothing wrong. Im considering to switch.